# How to monetdb log settings (merovingian.log)

Tags: monetdb

How to MonetDB log settings.

I want to change the log level of "merovingian.log".
I want to output the ERROR and WARN the merovingian.log.

But now merovingian.log is outputting only MSG log.

```
2016-07-22 18:12:03 MSG merovingian[7825]: proxying client x.x.x.x:51609 for database 'test' to mapi:monetdb:///var/MonetDB/dbfarm/test/.mapi.sock?database=test
2016-07-22 18:12:03 MSG merovingian[7825]: target connection is on local UNIX domain socket, passing on filedescriptor instead of proxying
```

OS is "CentOS 6.4",
MonetDB version is "MonetDB-11.19.7".

Any advice how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No fine-tuning is provided in where log information ends up.

Comment: Oh... 
Thank you answer !